# getpeername sa_data

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to get the IP address of the socket that's connected to my server socket.  I've included my code.

The sa_data doesn't return char[14] of the type "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx".  Instead, it returns `[11][1][xxx][xxx][xxx][xxx][][][][][][][]...[]`.  Can anyone help?

```
int InitialResult;
char SendMessage[1024];
char ReceiveMessage[1024];
WSADATA WSAData;
addrinfo Hints;
addrinfo *Result;
SOCKET ListenSocket;
SOCKET ClientSocket;

ZeroMemory(&Hints, sizeof(Hints));
Hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
Hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
Hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
Hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
while(1)
{
    InitialResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData);
    if (InitialResult != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSA start up failed.";
    }
    InitialResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, portnumber, &Hints, &Result);
    if (InitialResult != 0)
    {
        cout << "Get address information failed.";
        WSACleanup();
    }
    ListenSocket = socket(Result->ai_family, Result->ai_socktype, Result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket initialization failed.";
        WSACleanup();
    }
    InitialResult = bind(ListenSocket, Result->ai_addr, (int)Result->ai_addrlen);
    if (InitialResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Bind failed." << portnumber;
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        WSACleanup();
    }
    InitialResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (InitialResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Listen failed." << portnumber;
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        WSACleanup();
    }
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket accept failed." << portnumber;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    sockaddr test;
    int a = sizeof(test);
    cout << "getpeername() return value : " << getpeername(ClientSocket, &test, &a) << endl;
    cout << "test.sa_data : " << test.sa_data;


    StartReceive(ReceiveMessage, ClientSocket);
    strcpy(SendMessage,"Congratulations!! You have successfully transfered some data to G DA.");
    StartSend(SendMessage, ClientSocket);
    StartSend(portnumber, ClientSocket);
    InitialResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (InitialResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Shut down failed." << portnumber;
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second and third arguments of [`accept(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) allow you to get that information without extra call to [`getpeername(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpeername). Then you need to convert **binary address** to **string representation** with something like [`inet_ntoa(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think `WSADATA` should be a `char [14]`?  It's a `struct` as shown e.g. in [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741563(VS.85).aspx).

And BTW, in the various error cases you check, you should terminate the whole function (e.g. with a `return`), while what you're doing appears to be just to continue, after some message, with structures &c known to be invalid...

**Edit**: oh I see, when you say `sa_data` you mean `test.sa_data`, and another answer explained why it's not what you expect.  Leaving this answer in anyway since at least the second paragraph is pretty important (and still relevant;-).

Answer (score 0):

> The sa_data doesn't return char[14] of
>   the type "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

It isn't specified to do that, so no wonder it doesn't.

You need to look into sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6.